# How I can get the Stylus files icon for the files templates shared via IntelliJ IDEA plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I need the "styl" files icon instead of "?" one for my plugin with files templates:

[image]

Although I have found the appropriate icon in the [icons list](https://jetbrains.design/intellij/resources/icons_list/), I don't know how to set it.

[image]

I suppose, there is no such icon in **com.intellij.icons.AllIcons**.

```kotlin
class YDF_GUI_ComponentsTemplatesGroupFactory : FileTemplateGroupDescriptorFactory {
  override fun getFileTemplatesDescriptor(): FileTemplateGroupDescriptor {

    val groupDescriptor = FileTemplateGroupDescriptor("YDF GUI Components", AllIcons.Nodes.Folder)

    /* [ Theory ] No ".ft" must be here. */
    groupDescriptor.addTemplate(FileTemplateDescriptor("Badge.styl"))

    return groupDescriptor

  }
}
```

I am asking this question after [has not been answered in IDEs support forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/12760129005970-How-I-can-get-the-Stylus-files-icon-for-the-files-templates-shared-via-plugin-) for the 2 weeks.

Comment: It looks like the mentioned forum is not very active. Try to discuss this question via Slack channel or plugin development forum. Please see https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/getting-help.html#problems-with-code-support-issues